# GDB: File runs on Cent OS 7 but not Ubuntu

Tags: gdb

I am getting the below error when using the gdb command `run group3`.

[image]

I installed gdb on Windows Bash as well as an Ubuntu VM on Virtualbox and am getting the same error.

Some important notes:

- This program worked at my school using Cent OS 7
- I tried changing the file to have a .exe file extension but that didn't work. It should not require a file extension because it worked at my Uni without one.

Comment: What does `file group3` say?

Comment: `no debugging symbols found`

Comment: Sorry, run that command in the shell, please, not gdb.

Comment: `group3: ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, BuildID[sha1]=556d510630d81b76dba769c7315406abff0ce2a7, not stripped`

Comment: @MarkPlotnick They're both little endian, and my cpu is `x86_64` and `32-bit, 64-bit`, so it seems like everything is compatible...

Comment: On a real Ubuntu system, see the answer to https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/12956/49439 , which is to install the `ia32-libs` package. It's not clear if that will work on WSL.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick If the problem was "missing ia32", you'd get a "no such file or directory" (missing interpreter). To get `exec format error`, my money is on `ASCII` FTP transfer.

Comment: @EmployedRussian Sure, on a real Linux kernel. But `exec format error` is [what WSL shows for 32-bit executables](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/390), and I don't know whether they've fixed that yet. Tom, could you confirm the exact error you get on your Ubuntu VM?

Answer (score 0):

> This program worked at my school using Cent OS 7

Did you use `ftp` to copy this program into VM?

Chances are you did the transfer in `ASCII` mode, corrupting the binary in the process.

You can verify this has happened by running `md5sum group3` on both systems. If my guess is correct, the checksum will be different.

Use `binary` mode `FTP` instead, or use `scp`.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up corrupting my 64 bit Ubuntu VM when running out of space when trying to install the i386 packages. I ended up installing a new 32-bit Ubuntu VM and the program ran on that successfully.